# Find set of strings of maximum size that are far apart

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a set S of binary strings of the same length, what is a fast way to find a maximum size subset S' of S with the property that the Hamming distance between every pair of strings in S' is at least d?

The following function computes the Hamming distance between two strings.

```
def hamdist(str1, str2):
    """Count the # of differences between equal length strings str1 and str2"""
    if (len(str1) != len(str2)):
        print str1, str2, "Length mismatch!"
        quit()
    diffs = 0
    for ch1, ch2 in itertools.izip(str1, str2):
        if ch1 != ch2:
            diffs += 1
    return diffs
```

Comment: This is maximum clique problem.

Comment: Do you mean maximal or maximum? For clique, a maximal clique is simply one where it cannot be made larger by adding another vertex (or string in this case). It sounds like it might actually be maximal, in which case, the graph Sam Mussmann describes should make it easier enough to do.

Comment: @Nuclearman Thanks. I meant maximum (it was supposed to refer to the size of the subset and not the subset itself in any case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Falk notes, in order to prove that this problem is NP-hard, we need a reduction *from* an NP-hard problem. I'm going to use the problem of finding an independent set (i.e., finding a clique in the complement graph).

My reduction has two stages. The output of the first stage is a generalized instance with a non-binary alphabet. The output of the second stage uses a binary alphabet. Let G = (V, E) be the graph in which we are trying to find a large independent set. The output of the first stage is |V| words of length |E|. Let e = (v, w) be the i<sup>th</sup> edge. The letters in the i<sup>th</sup> position of each word are all different except for the words corresponding to v and w, which share a letter there. The size of the alphabet is thus |V| - 1. Two vertices are non-adjacent if and only if their words are at maximum distance, so we set the distance threshold to |V|.

In the second stage, we replace each letter by one of the |V| - 1 words of length |V| - 1 that has 1 "1" and (|V| - 2) "0"s and double the distance threshold to 2 |V|.

To solve small instances, I would recommend using Sam's reduction to the maximum clique problem and running the exponential-time [Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron-Kerbosch_algorithm) to enumerate all *maximal* cliques, from which the maximum can be selected. (Why B–K and not the faster algorithms? The latter are more complicated and won't extend your reach very far.)

Comment: Thanks. So I suppose the best route is to code it up so I can use http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc-0.6.5/python/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#largest_cliques .

Comment: @marshall Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Egor's comment:

Imagine you have a graph `G` which has one vertex for each string in `S`.  Now, for each pair of vertices `v1`, `v2` find the Hamming distance between the corresponding strings `s1`, `s2`.  If it's more than `d`, add an edge to `G` between `v1` and `v2`.

Now, you want to find the maximal subset of `S` such that every pair of strings in this maximal subset has Hamming distance at least `d` between them.  The corresponding problem on the graph we just constructed is to find the maximum set of vertices such that every vertex in that set is connected to every other vertex in that set.

This is the [Maximum Clique problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs).  If you click through that link to the wikipedia article, you'll find that the best known algorithm to solve this runs in `O(1.2599^n)` time, which is exponential, and thus not fast.  If you could solve your problem quickly (that is to say, in polynomial time), then you could solve the Maximum Clique problem in polynomial time using this correspondence, so there's no fast solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there code I can use?  There are sometimes very fast heuristics that work well in practice for random instances for NP-Hard problems.

Comment: Maybe http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc-0.6.5/python/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#largest_cliques is the best choice?

Comment: The fact that you can reduce the problem to Clique does not imply anything about its NP-hardness. For that, you need to reduce Clique to your problem. That is, given a graph, you need to come up with the strings that will yield the graph structure.

Comment: @FalkHüffner A very good point.  Do you think it is NP-hard?  In some sense I actually don't care as I want to solve it for small random instances in any case. I just want some code :)